# Can't run android app on Samsung Galaxy S5 from mac os x

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb, samsung-mobile

I'm totally new on android studio and now I try to run my app on samsung galaxy s5. I installed sdk, adb, etc. I enabled samsung device for developer options : http://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-samsung-galaxy-s5-developer-options 
but when I start running the app, android studio doesn't find my device and in android console I have a button with red text: No connected devices.
I can run my app only in emulator.

I found another questions similar with this on stackoverflow, but there were solutions for windows not mac or that solutions doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

In your phone, Go to setting find "Developer options" and tick the USB debugging

Comment: I mentioned that I followed those steps. @Le Parkout

Comment: Did you install your phone USB driver for your mac?

Comment: I found samsung phone USB only for windows, not for mac. I don't know if it works if I install motorola USB driver. Have you any idea? http://www.samsung.com/us/smart-switch/?Nt=y# this doesn't work

Comment: Try to detect your samsung phone media connect before use for debugging, probably your Mac can't detect your phone yet.

Comment: After connecting your phone to your mac with the USB cable, pull down on the notification bar at the top of the screen on your phone. Click on it where it says "USB connected" and then select "Mount" and better install Salling Media Sync